# slackware 14.2x64 on hp laptop, startx fails

Tags: x11, configuration, laptop, slackware, hp

Have slackware 14.2x64 dual-booting with native gpt/uefi windows 10 on a

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/hp-17-3-laptop-intel-core-i7-8gb-memory-1tb-hard-drive-black/5884843.p?skuId=5884843

They both boot okay, but slackware startx fails. /var/log/Xorg.0.log says

```
(EE) No devices detected.
(EE) No screens found.
```

I first tried startx after installing slackware without any X configuration. Then I tried running xorgsetup, and just pressed Return to select defaults for the several options. Exact same problem, although the /etc/X11/xorg.conf file looked okay to me. But I don't know much about that stuff. The relevant sections (I think) are

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver     "intel"
  BusID      "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

and similarly vanilla stuff for Card0 and Monitor0, and keyboard, mouse, etc. Booting windows works fine, and says the graphics are "Intel HD Graphics 620", and "Generic PnP Monitor". And they both work fine on the linux F1,F2,... terminals. Even the touchpad works (using gpm).

Not quite sure how to best proceed debugging/configuring the problem. Since slackware 12 or so, I haven't had to do any X-configuration at all. startx just worked as soon as the install was completed. But not this time:(. Any suggestions how to proceed? Thanks.

**Edit/Answer**
Got it working using generic framebuffer device fbdev, although that's no longer default installed (at least not with slackware).

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier "Card0"
  Driver     "fbdev"
  BusID      "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```